# No Encuentra Variable PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, variables

Al intentar hacer un insert en una tabla me arroja el siguiente Notice:

Notice: Undefined variable: iva in C:\xampp\htdocs\remision\ajax\editar_facturacion.php on line 17

y no agrega el Valor del IVA

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            load(1);
            $( "#resultados" ).load( "ajax/editar_facturacion.php" );
        });

function load(page){
            var q= $("#q").val();
            $("#loader").fadeIn('slow');
            $.ajax({
                url:'./ajax/productos_factura.php?action=ajax&page='+page+'&q='+q,
                 beforeSend: function(objeto){
                 $('#loader').html('<img src="./img/ajax-loader.gif"> Cargando...');
              },
                success:function(data){
                    $(".outer_div").html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                    $('#loader').html('');

                }
            })
}

function agregar (id)
        {
            var precio_venta=document.getElementById('precio_venta_'+id).value;
            var cantidad=document.getElementById('cantidad_'+id).value;
            var iva=document.getElementById('iva_'+id).value;
            //Inicia validacion
            if (isNaN(cantidad))
            {
            alert('Esto no es un numero');
            document.getElementById('cantidad_'+id).focus();
            return false;
            }
            if (isNaN(precio_venta))
            {
            alert('Esto no es un numero');
            document.getElementById('precio_venta_'+id).focus();
            return false;
            }
            if (isNaN(iva))
            {
            alert('Esto no es un numero');
            document.getElementById('iva_'+id).focus();
            return false;
            }
            //Fin validacion

            $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./ajax/editar_facturacion.php",
        data: "id="+id+"&precio_venta="+precio_venta+"&iva="+iva+"&cantidad="+cantidad,
         beforeSend: function(objeto){
            $("#resultados").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
          },
        success: function(datos){
        $("#resultados").html(datos);
        }
            });
}

function eliminar (id)
        {

            $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./ajax/editar_facturacion.php",
        data: "id="+id,
         beforeSend: function(objeto){
            $("#resultados").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
          },
        success: function(datos){
        $("#resultados").html(datos);
        }
            });

        }

        $("#datos_factura").submit(function(event){
          var id_cliente = $("#id_cliente").val();

          if (id_cliente==""){
              alert("Debes seleccionar un cliente");
              $("#nombre_cliente").focus();
              return false;
          }
            var parametros = $(this).serialize();
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/editar_factura.php",
                    data: parametros,
                     beforeSend: function(objeto){
                        $(".editar_factura").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
                      },
                    success: function(datos){
                        $(".editar_factura").html(datos);
                    }
            });

             event.preventDefault();
        });

        $( "#guardar_cliente" ).submit(function( event ) {
          $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", true);

         var parametros = $(this).serialize();
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/nuevo_cliente.php",
                    data: parametros,
                     beforeSend: function(objeto){
                        $("#resultados_ajax").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
                      },
                    success: function(datos){
                    $("#resultados_ajax").html(datos);
                    $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);
                    load(1);
                  }
            });
          event.preventDefault();
        })

        $( "#guardar_producto" ).submit(function( event ) {
          $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", true);

         var parametros = $(this).serialize();
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/nuevo_producto.php",
                    data: parametros,
                     beforeSend: function(objeto){
                        $("#resultados_ajax_productos").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
                      },
                    success: function(datos){
                    $("#resultados_ajax_productos").html(datos);
                    $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);
                    load(1);
                  }
            });
          event.preventDefault();
        })

function imprimir_factura(id_factura){
            VentanaCentrada('./pdf/documentos/ver_factura.php?id_factura='+id_factura,'Factura','','1024','768','true');
        }
```

---

y aqui el Ajax:

```
   <?php
include('is_logged.php');//Archivo verifica que el usario que intenta acceder a la URL esta logueado
$id_factura= $_SESSION['id_factura'];
$numero_factura= $_SESSION['numero_factura'];
if (isset($_POST['id'])){$id=intval($_POST['id']);}
if (isset($_POST['cantidad'])){$cantidad=floatval($_POST['cantidad']);}
if (isset($_POST['iva'])){$iva=floatval($_POST['iva']);}
if (isset($_POST['precio_venta'])){$precio_venta=floatval($_POST['precio_venta']);}

    /* Connect To Database*/
    require_once ("../config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
    require_once ("../config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
    //Archivo de funciones PHP
    include("../funciones.php");
if (!empty($id) and !empty($cantidad) and !empty($precio_venta))
{
$insert_tmp=mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO detalle_factura (numero_factura, id_producto, cantidad, iva, precio_venta) VALUES ('$numero_factura','$id','$cantidad','$iva','$precio_venta')");

}
if (isset($_GET['id']))//codigo elimina un elemento del array
{
$id_detalle=intval($_GET['id']);    
$delete=mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM detalle_factura WHERE id_detalle='".$id_detalle."'");
}
$simbolo_moneda=get_row('perfil','moneda', 'id_perfil', 1);
?>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th class='text-center'>CODIGO</th>
    <th class='text-center'>CANT.</th>
    <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
    <th class='text-right'>PRECIO UNIT.</th>
    <th class='text-right'>IVA</th>
    <th class='text-right'>PRECIO TOTAL</th>
    <th></th>
</tr>
<?php
    $sumador_total=0;
    $sumador_total2=0;
    $sumador_iva=0;
    $sql=mysqli_query($con, "select * from products, facturas, detalle_factura where facturas.numero_factura=detalle_factura.numero_factura and  facturas.id_factura='$id_factura' and products.id_producto=detalle_factura.id_producto");
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    $id_detalle=$row["id_detalle"];
    $codigo_producto=$row['codigo_producto'];
    $cantidad=$row['cantidad'];
    $nombre_producto=$row['nombre_producto'];

    $precio_sin_iva=$row['subtotal'];
    $precio_sin_iva_f=number_format($precio_sin_iva,2);//Formateo variables
    $precio_sin_iva_r=str_replace(",","",$precio_sin_iva_f);//Reemplazo las comas
    $precio_total2=$precio_sin_iva_r*$cantidad;
    $precio_total2_f=number_format($precio_total2,2);//Precio total formateado
    $precio_total2_r=str_replace(",","",$precio_total2_f);//Reemplazo las comas
    $sumador_total2+=$precio_total2_r;//Sumador del precio sin iva

    $precio_venta=$row['precio_venta'];
    $precio_venta_f=number_format($precio_venta,2);//Formateo variables
    $precio_venta_r=str_replace(",","",$precio_venta_f);//Reemplazo las comas
    $precio_total=$precio_venta_r*$cantidad;
    $precio_total_f=number_format($precio_total,2);//Precio total formateado
    $precio_total_r=str_replace(",","",$precio_total_f);//Reemplazo las comas
    $sumador_total+=$precio_total_r;//Sumador

    $iva=$row['iva'];
    $iva_f=number_format($iva,2);//Formateo variables
    $iva_r=str_replace(",","",$iva_f);//Reemplazo las comas
    $iva_total=$iva_r*$cantidad;
    $iva_total_f=number_format($iva_total,2);//Precio total formateado
    $iva_total_r=str_replace(",","",$iva_total_f);//Reemplazo las comas
    $sumador_iva+=$iva_total_r;//Sumador iva

        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class='text-center'><?php echo $codigo_producto;?></td>
            <td class='text-center'><?php echo $cantidad;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $nombre_producto;?></td>
            <td class='text-right'><?php echo $precio_sin_iva_f;?></td>
            <td class='text-right'><?php echo $iva_f;?></td>
            <td class='text-right'><?php echo $precio_total_f;?></td>
            <td class='text-center'><a href="#" onclick="eliminar('<?php echo $id_detalle ?>')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
        </tr>       
        <?php
    }
    $impuesto=get_row('perfil','impuesto', 'id_perfil', 1);
    $subtotal=number_format($sumador_total,2,'.','');
    $total_iva=($subtotal * $impuesto )/100;
    $total_iva=number_format($total_iva,2,'.','');
    $total_factura=$subtotal+$total_iva;
    $update=mysqli_query($con,"update facturas set total_venta='$total_factura' where id_factura='$id_factura'");
?>
<tr>
    <td class='text-right' colspan=4>SUBTOTAL <?php echo $simbolo_moneda;?></td>
    <td class='text-right'><?php echo number_format($sumador_total2,2);?></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='text-right' colspan=4>IVA <?php echo $simbolo_moneda;?></td>
    <td class='text-right'><?php echo number_format($sumador_iva,2);?></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='text-right' colspan=4>AGREGADO (<?php echo $impuesto;?>)% <?php echo $simbolo_moneda;?></td>
    <td class='text-right'><?php echo number_format($total_iva,2);?></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='text-right' colspan=4>TOTAL <?php echo $simbolo_moneda;?></td>
    <td class='text-right'><?php echo number_format($total_factura,2);?></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

---

y aqui la estructura de la base 
[image: base]

Y aca el Input

```
<?php
include('is_logged.php');//Archivo verifica que el usario que intenta acceder a la URL esta logueado
/* Connect To Database*/
require_once ("../config/db.php");//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
require_once ("../config/conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';
if($action == 'ajax'){
    // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
     $q = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['q'], ENT_QUOTES)));
     $aColumns = array('codigo_producto', 'nombre_producto' );//Columnas de busqueda
     $sTable = "products";
     $sWhere = "";
    if ( $_GET['q'] != "" )
    {
        $sWhere = "WHERE (";
        for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
        {
            $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".$q."%' OR ";
        }
        $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
        $sWhere .= ')';
    }
    include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
    //pagination variables
    $page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
    $per_page = 5; //how much records you want to show
    $adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
    //Count the total number of row in your table*/
    $count_query   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $sTable  $sWhere");
    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query);
    $numrows = $row['numrows'];
    $total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
    $reload = './index.php';
    //main query to fetch the data
    $sql="SELECT * FROM  $sTable $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    //loop through fetched data
    if ($numrows>0){

        ?>
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <tr  class="warning">
                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th><span class="pull-right">Cant.</span></th>
                <th><span class="pull-right">Precio</span></th>
                <th><span class="pull-right">IVA</span></th>
                <th class='text-center' style="width: 36px;">Agregar</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $id_producto=$row['id_producto'];
                $codigo_producto=$row['codigo_producto'];
                $nombre_producto=$row['nombre_producto'];
                $precio_venta=$row["precio_producto"];
                $precio_venta=number_format($precio_venta,2,'.','');
                $iva=$row["iva"];
                $iva=number_format($iva,2,'.','');
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $codigo_producto; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $nombre_producto; ?></td>
                    <td class='col-xs-1'>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" id="cantidad_<?php echo $id_producto; ?>" value="1" >
                    </div></td>
                    <td class='col-xs-2'><div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" id="precio_venta_<?php echo $id_producto; ?>" value="<?php echo $precio_venta;?>" readonly >
                    </div></td>
                    <td class='col-xs-2'><div class="pull-right">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" id="iva_<?php echo $id_producto; ?>" value="<?php echo $iva;?>" readonly>
                    </div></td>
                    <td class='text-center'><a class='btn btn-info'href="#" onclick="agregar('<?php echo $id_producto ?>')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=5><span class="pull-right">
                <?php
                 echo paginate($reload, $page, $total_pages, $adjacents);
                ?></span></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Espero Me puedan ayudar por que llevo horas rompiéndome el coco con esto.
De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: te recomiendo que empieces a depurar paso a paso... de principio al fin.. y así destacas donde puede estar el fallo... también echaría un vistazo sobre [SQLi](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php)...

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el html en el que debería haber un input con el "iva_venta"?

Comment: Listo! Muchisimas Gracias, ya estuve revisando linea por linea y no encuentro el problema. P.D. La variable la Cambie solo por IVA en la base de datos tambien

Comment: Te faltó explicar que el error te lo da en el ajax. Los otros scripts son más bien de presentación de data

Comment: Traté de indentar un poco mejor el código...

Comment: Usa devtools para ver la cadena de data que envías por `POST`, y revisa del lado del servidor qué le llega en `$_POST` a `editar_facturacion.php`. Si `$iva` es undefined significa que `isset($_POST['iva'])` no se cumple

Comment: Tu código es mejorable en muchísimos aspectos. Por ejemplo: en tus peticiones Ajax no manejas posibles fallos, sólo manejas el `success`... bien bien, pero no vivimos en un mundo perfecto y algo puede fallar. Si no implementas un `fail`, nunca sabrás que está fallando. Se recomienda usar `done`y `fail`(success es obsoleto). Luego, haces una petición Ajax al mismo archivo: una con el método `GET` y otra con el método `POST`. ¿A qué se debe eso?  Depura la variable `data` que envías vía Ajax, puede que no esté bien formada. Cuando resuelvas eso, deberás darle una mirada a la Inyección SQL.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por ayudar a esta alma en pena, este es mi primer desarrollo y se que tengo un largo camino por delante.

Creo que ya se por donde va el problema, voy a trabajar sobre el y posteo mi resultado para ver si a alguien le sirve en un futuro.

Answer (score 0):

No veo la consulta que haces a la base de datos, pero creo que tu problema está en el nombre del campo dela base de datos.

En la base de datos el campo se llama ***"iva_venta"*** y tu lo estas intentando sacar con sólo ***"iva"***.

Cambia    ***`$iva=$row["iva"];`***   por    ***`$iva=$row["iva_venta"];`***